# If $S,T$ are stopping times, then is it necessary that $S-T$ is a stopping time?

Tags: stochastic-processes

If $S,T$ are stopping times in discrete-time, then I know $S+T$ is a stopping time. Is it necessary that $S-T$ is a stopping time? Intuitively, I can see that $S-T$ involves some events happening in the future, and hence not a stopping time. Can anyone give me some examples?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your intuition is correct, $S-T$ is not necessarily a stopping time. For a counterexample, consider the simple random walk $(X_n)$ on $\mathbb Z$ started at zero, and let $S=\inf\{n:X_n=1\}$ and $T=1$. Note that $\{S-T\le1\}=\{S\le2\}$ which is not $X_1$-measurable.

Comment: Why $\{S-T\le1\}=\{S\le2\}$ is not $X_{1}$-measurable?

Comment: Uh, in this particular case, it turns out it *is* $X_1$-measurable, oops. If we instead assume $(X_n)$ is a *lazy* simple random walk (so the jump sizes are $-1,0,1$ with probability $1/3$ each), then $\{S\le2\}=\{X_1=1\}\cup\{X_1=0,X_2-X_1=1\}$, which is not $X_1$-measurable since $X_2-X_1$ is independent of $X_1$.